# Existence of a bounded measurable subset of $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ that is Borel isomorphic to $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, measure-theory, homogeneous-spaces, haar-measure

$\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ has two interesting properties: on one hand it is non-compact, but on the other hand it admits a unique $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$-invariant *finite* measure on $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$.

I wonder if there exists a bounded measurable subset $F$ of $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ (with subspace topology, of course) that is Borel isomorphic to $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$?

By "Borel isomorphic" I mean: There exists a bijection $f:F\subset \text{SL}(d,\mathbb R) \to \text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ such that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are Borel measurable, with $F$ inheriting the subspace topology from $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$. Of course, "up to a subset of measure zero" is always allowed.

If this is true, then it is good to know a constructive proof but the proof for the existence of such an $F$ will also be greatly appreciated!

---

Here I am not assuming $F$ is a "fundamental domain" for $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$, whose definition itself has many interpretations and I asked $F$ to be bounded and thus *may not be homeomorphic to* $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ (but as a possible approach one may want to construct such an $F$ whose closure is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ modulo a set of measure zero). I only want this $F$ to be *measure theoretically isomorphic to* $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ but not topologically. Disproving this claim seems also very hard.

Comment: Existence of $F$ is clear, because any non-discrete Polish space is Borel isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @GHfromMO Thanks! One more question: Suppose $\mu$ is the Haar measure on $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ and $\tilde{\mu}$ is the induced probability Haar measure on $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ can we also make $\mu(F)=\tilde{\mu}(\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z))$ happen?

Comment: There is no Haar measure on $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ as it is not a group.

Comment: @GHfromMO Sorry I meant $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$-invariant measure on $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$. Then it exists.

Comment: Yes, you can make that happen. See my answer, and note that the measure of the $F$ constructed there can be chosen to be an arbitrary positive number.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense, as $SL_{d}(\mathbb{R})/SL_{d}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a standard probability space.

Comment: @GHfromMO Sorry I haven't logged in for a while.. just did it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Iwasawa decomposition, $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n\times\text{SO}(d,\mathbb R)$, where $n=(d^2+d-2)/2$. As $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to any open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it follows that $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ is homeomorphic to a bounded Borel subset of $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$; this homeomorphism can be constructed explicitly. Now take a nice fundamental domain of $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$; e.g. take a suitable Borel subset. We see that this fundamental domain is also homeomorphic to a bounded Borel subset of $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$, and we are done.